# Index for data driven page created atlas?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, data-driven-pages

We have a parcel atlas created from a data driven page document where each page represents a particular 16 mile square township.  I have created my own index of polygons instead of ArcGIS index creation because we are looking for a slight overlap.  I would like to create or tweak a python script to clip the area for each page and pull out owner name information for each township; better yet, would be each 1 square mile section in order to create a index of names/ area.  Anyone know of something similar or can point me in a direction of more information.  I am relatively new with python but understand the basics pretty well.

Comment: What is your end goal product? A popup table in an exported map? A dbf table that you can query from? Also, does your parcels layer contain township/section attributes?

Comment: @10.1 you can create that with the legend limiter functionality.

Answer (score 3):

There is an excellent article written about generating pdf-documents using arcpy. It takes you through the basics and also shows more sophisticated features.

- [Combining data driven pages with Python and arcpy.mapping](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/12/14/combining-data-driven-pages-with-python-and-arcpy-mapping/)

You can  easily generate an index page using [pyfpdf](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/10/an-intro-to-pyfpdf-a-simple-python-pdf-generation-library/). With arcpy you also  have access to the contents of your polygon index dbf-file.